# Identify and calculate area of valleys

Tags: qgis, dem

I have a shapefile (points) that contains the coordinates of a number of cities in a mountainous area (valleys separated by mountain ridges), and a DEM of the area. I would like to calculate the approximate size (area) of the valley each city is located in, using QGIS.

Of course, this depends on how you define a valley. I guess I would need a combination of elevation and slope.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do this?

Comment: What about using a ``watershed`` algorithm from  GRASS or SAGA through the Processing Toolbox? Don't know if you can consider the results as valleys, but maybe you can start from this

Comment: I don't know if this is an answer to your question, but I notice that there is a GRASS Addon called "r.valley.bottom - Calculation of Multi-resolution Valley Bottom Flatness (MrVBF) index".  You can find more info at [link](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.valley.bottom.html)